# How can I use git/AWS CLI to manage AWS Lambda code?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, version-control, aws-lambda

I have approximately 10 microservices implemented as Node.js lambdas in AWS. 
What is the best way to manage them through git and the AWS CLI? I am currently editing them through the web interface but it is starting to be difficult to manage.

Comment: Are you looking for automation (DevOps) or manual updates of your Lambda function? Look into the CLI update-function-code for command line Lambda updates. There is no integration between git and cli. For a DevOps solution look at Tom Melo's answer.

Comment: Git VCS and AWS CLI are quite different tools. So you'd better decide which tool to use before asking how to manage your code.

Comment: Thanks John and Marina. I will check the CLI update-function-code. For now I am in manual, although to Marina's point at some point I might have to automate and stop relying on AWS CLI for pushing the code

Answer (score 4):

I would very strongly suggest you to use [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless)!

It has made management and deployment so much easier for lambda architecture and additionally it also gives you ease of coding since it is a 'framework'

Comment: Thanks! I will look into serverless in detail as everyone is talking about it

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) + [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) + [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) + [CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) for your version control and CI/CD. There's a heavy lift when using CloudFormation, but as soon as you get things up and running the process of deploying new Lambda versions becomes super easy.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I use CodeCommit now, and as you said have found the other Clouds a bit of a heavy life. Seems it is the time to go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Vercel](https://vercel.com).

Not only can you deploy your functions with `git push` but the branch context is considered. For example, pushing to a PR branch creates a Preview deployment with a unique URL that represents your PR. Merging that PR to your main branch creates a Production deployment with your production domain.

There's even a free tier for Hobby projects so you can try it out yourself without any commitment.